# behavior of a Sql Server availability group listener and a jdbc client during a failover?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, high-availability

i have a question about the behavior of the AG listener during a failover... when the failover happens, I realize that all the connections on both primary and secondaries are closed.

if the client apps are using one of the blessed client libraries (such as microsoft jdbc > 6.0) they will then start immediately trying to reconnect to the ip addresses associated with the listener. But what happens during the 10 second period (or whatever it is) for the failover to complete? Might a client successfully get a connection, only to get a fatal error message when it tries to use it? Or is something done to ensure that no client will get a connection successfully during failover itself, so that that when a client does successfully get a connection, it is actually usable?

(FYI regarding the behavior of the microsoft jdbc driver, judging from the source code at:
https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java
It will divide the configured loginTimeout by 8 and so make 8 attempts before timing out.)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that no client is going to be able to connect to the Listener and get a database connection until the failover completes. Look at the section "How Automatic Failover Works" in the following link. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/failover-and-failover-modes-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=During%20the%20failover%2C%20the%20failover,its%20databases%20become%20secondary%20databases.)

Comment: Ah, and that article links to: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover?view=sql-server-ver15
and that in turn says:

The instance of SQL Server will verify the state of the targeted database and either allow or disallow connectivity based on the configuration of the availability group and the current state of the database on the instance. .... If the target database is offline or in a transitional state, connectivity to the database will fail.

I think that answers it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> what happens during the 10 second period (or whatever it is) for the failover to complete?

This is what the "loginTimeout" is for:

> The number of seconds the driver should wait before timing out a
> failed connection. A zero value indicates that the timeout is the
> default system timeout, which is specified as 15 seconds by default. A
> non-zero value is the number of seconds the driver should wait before
> timing out a failed connection.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-ver15

> Might a client successfully get a connection, only to get a fatal error message when it tries to use it

That is *possible* as the network connection becomes available before the AG comes online,  which happens before database recovery, and if there is an unusual delay between the two you could get connected before the database has recovered.